# Form submit method POST adding backlashes before quotes (" to \")

Tags: php, post

I just moved my site from one server to another, I was testing the site when I discovered a a bug. The problem was that when submitting a form the new server was transforming strings such as this: `hello"world` to `hello\"world`.

How can I prevent this from happening or unescape characters with php? I don't want to use a regex or something to replace the occurrences in case sometime I actually need to write `\"` in a string.

---

EDIT - This is the content of my php.ini

```
; Rename this file to php.ini and uncomment or add directives.
; For a complete list of valid directives, visit:
;  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.php

[PHP]
; We highly recommend that you leave this options enabled
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
;open_basedir = "/home/172652/domains"

; Increase maximum post size
;post_max_size = 20M

; Increase execution time
;max_execution_time = 300

; pull in EGPCS [Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server] variables as globals
;register_globals = true

; For performance reasons, (mt) does not load all of the modules that are available
; into PHP. You may uncomment any one of the following "extension" lines to enable
; the desired module

; Salblotron XSLT
;extension=xslt.so

; save in local tmp
session.save_path=/home/172652/data/tmp
```

Comment: Check your php settings in php.ini and make sure that magic quotes is turned off.

Comment: I just edited with my php.ini

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

Upgrade PHP to the latest version (where they are no longer supported) or [turn them off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) by setting:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't know it could be turned on without being in php.ini